# c++ - `this` pointer changes to null after returning from a destroyed function object

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, g++, clang++

The following code

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class State {
    void first_shot()
    {
        std::cout << "foo start " << this << std::endl;
        this->x = [=]()
        {
            std::cout << "baz " << this << std::endl;
        };
        std::cout << "foo end " << this << std::endl;
    }
public:
    std::function<void()> x;

    State()
    {
        this->x = [=]()
        {
            std::cout << "bar start " << this << std::endl;
            this->first_shot();

            /* HERE */
            std::cout << "bar end " << this << std::endl;
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    State s;
    s.x();
    s.x();
    return 0;
}
```

runs quite weirdly when compile with `g++ -std=c++0x`. At the line after comment `HERE`, `this` becomes a null pointer. In fact as long as `this->x` is changed to null function pointer or bound to any other function during `this->first_shot()`, `this` would change to null AFTER the call.

I've tested it under Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and CentOS 7 (both are g++ 4.8.2). It's not reproducable when compile with clang++ (`this` pointer won't change).

Is that a misuse of `std::function`? It's considerable when the function object is destroyed the values (in this situation is `this`) bound to it becomes invalid.

So I would like to fix this problem with a simple change to the latter lambda

```
this->x = [=]()
{
    State* me = this;
    std::cout << "bar start " << me << std::endl;
    me->first_shot();
    std::cout << "bar end " << me << std::endl;
};
```

The fixed code is OK, isn't it?

BTW, before I compile & run it with g++, the binary clang++ produces runs without any problem, no memory errors shows up even with valgrind. I wonder how clang do the things "just right" (is it just right?)

Comment: You are changing `x` while you are in the middle of executing it. By the time you return from `first_shot`, the `lambda` function that `x` used to be has been deleted. Sounds like recipe for undefined behavior.

Comment: I think a better fix would be to make the code less spaghetti.

Comment: @RSahu Since the function object binds only `this` in the context, is the fix which has a copy of `this` fine? I see that function object is destructed, but the function execution (which should be placed in the code segment) won't be invalidated, right?

Comment: @RSahu is right, I don't think this has anything to do with `this` being null. The fact is, after `this->first_shot()` finishes, control returns to `this->x()`. Except, the point in the lambda you re-enter at may be gone, since you've reassigned `this->x`. If it ends up working correctly, it just means nothing yet has overwritten the memory your lambda was sitting in.

Comment: This sounds like a compiler bug, to me. I don't think the lambdas should be tied to the `function` object. I don't have a copy of the standard available to check, though.